# No error or data returned while connecting to twitter stream via tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

The following is my code to read data from the twitter stream. When I try to run it via my terminal, neither data is returned, nor any error is returned. The following traceback is returned when I kill the process:

```
File "Soundcloud.py", line 59, in <module>
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['soundcloud.com'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 430, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 255, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 298, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 171, in read_line
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 243, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 588, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 630, in _read_chunked
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 734, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 621, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
```

My code is given below:

```
    import tweepy
    from tweepy import Stream
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    import json
    import time
    import pymysql
    import sys
    import extraction
    import requests
    import codecs
    import urllib2
    import urllib 
    from urllib import urlopen
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    #twitter Authentication-keys not entered
    consumer_key = ''
    consumer_secret = '' 
    access_token = ''
    access_secret = ''

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)


    global conn
    conn=pymysql.connect(db='twitter_users', user='root' , host='127.0.0.1' , port=3307)
    global cursor
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    class MyListener(StreamListener):

     def on_status(self, status):
        tweet_json=json.loads(status)
        print(tweet_json)
        for i in tweet_json:
            user_handle=i['user']['screen_name']
            user_followers=i['user']['followers_count']
            user_statuses=i['user']['statuses_count']
            user_location=i['user']['location']
            user_geo=i['geo']
            tweet_place=i['place']
            tweet_device=i['source']
            tweet_id=i['id_str']
            url=i['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']
        print(url)
        return True

     def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

     def on_timeout(self):
        print("Received timeout. Sleeping for 20 secs")
        time.sleep(20)
        return True

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['soundcloud.com'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things incorrect with the code.

1. `on_status` does not return a `JSON` object it returns `ResultSet`. Those information are accessed using `user_handle=status.user.screen_name`
2. You don't need a `for` loop within the `on_status` function. It loops by itself when every tweet is obtained.

Fix those errors and see if that changes anything.